# How to reset SQL Server Inbuilt Function (DAY)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to update my column in the table called `[DAY]` and didn't realize that there was also an inbuilt function `DAY`. So I accidentally updated the `DAY` value instead causing it to show `'N.A'` which is the value I've set.

I've tried searching on google but no matches appear, tried finding the inbuilt functions on SQL Server but to no avail.

The update code was this:

```
UPDATE v_ClassroomOccupancy SET
  [DAY] = (CASE WHEN (LocalTime NOT BETWEEN CLASSSTARTDATE AND CLASSENDDATE) THEN 'N.A' ELSE DAY END)
```

Any way I can reset or set `DAY` inbuilt function to the default value?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking? You won't have used the inbuilt `day()` function unless you used it with brackets - since its a function. So what got set wrong? And what are you hoping to do?

Comment: There is no way you can "reset the day function". So whatever you are seeing is NOT due to to changing some inbuilt value. What you can do is change the first day of week number (normally Sunday is day 1) with a SET command, but I dont think thats what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DAY` is reserved keyword in `SQL Server`, since you already named your column as `DAY`, make sure to enclosed this to brackets `[]` each time you are using this column.

```
UPDATE v_ClassroomOccupancy SET

[DAY]=(CASE WHEN(LocalTime NOT BETWEEN CLASSSTARTDATE AND CLASSENDDATE) THEN 'N.A' ELSE [DAY] END)
```

To reset your `[DAY]` Column, use `getdate()` function to get your current `datetime`

```
UPDATE v_ClassroomOccupancy SET

[DAY]=(CASE WHEN GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN CLASSSTARTDATE AND CLASSENDDATE THEN 'N.A' ELSE datename(dw, GETDATE()) END)
```

Comment: Ok. is there any way to reset the value of day? or something. cause every time i create a view with a column [day] it will return N.A.

Comment: It didnt work, anyways thanks for the help. ill just change my column name to something else either then day. do u  want to see my table columns?

Comment: sure, add your table schema

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi could you clarify how this resolved your issue?

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi, any sample data of [Day] value?

Comment: in that same table, the values are just the days in the week. example, Monday , Tuesday ,Wednesday and the others

Comment: great, try the 2nd query again

Comment: Just a heads up metal. this problem only occurs in a view. like when I create a view with 3 tables or a view + a table then the day column would stay at n.a.

Comment: in the original table containing the [day] column it does not have any problems, only when I create the view then the day column from the original table becomes n.a. ive tried using different view names.  I've tried the second query but it didn't help.

Comment: can you share your view script?

Comment: if you run your select script, it will work, but if you create the view, it will get an error, what's the error message?

Comment: there is no error, the view would be created correctly. just that the [day] column is filled with 'n.a' for all the rows

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi, the view is just a wrapper of your queries, the actual values still exist on the actual table, if you run `select [Day] From ClassTimeTable' are you getting n.a?

Comment: nope. when i run the query all the days come out. not a single n.a' anywhere